# Checking Understanding of DFA Regular Operations - Intersection and Star

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

I'm currently taking a Logics course, and trying to understand the regular operations, intersection and star. I have a question regarding the work I have done so far.

Given the following information:

> $L_A$ and $L_B$ are regular languages defined by DFAs $A$ and $B$.
>   $N_A$ and $N_B$ are the number of states in DFAs $A$ and $B$.
>
> What are the HIGHEST number of states one would need in DFAs for the languages
>
> 1. $L_A \cap L_B$
> 2. ${L_A}^*$ (star)

**INTERSECTION** operation

I have understood it so that the state of the new automaton A∩B will be the pairs of states in A and B. That is:

Na∩b = Na x Nb.

That is, the HIGHEST number of states needed in the DFA for language A∩B is the product of the number of states in *A* (Na) and *B* (Nb). Is this correct?

Another question: how does this number differ from the highest number of states in the **CONCATENATION** operation?

**STAR** operation:

For the star operation, I'm at a loss. Any advice on how I can approach this?

Comment: "Highest needed" = "minimal DFA"?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is formally incorrect because you are using the same notation for a language and an automaton and also because your notation $Na \cap b$ is not clear at all.
However, the meaning of your question is clear and the answer is known, but not easy. 
So let me first reformulate your question in a more rigorous way and then give the answer.

The (state) complexity of a regular language $L$ is the number of states $c(L)$ of its minimal DFA.

**Question 1**. Estimate $\max\{ c(L_1 \cap L_2) \mid c(L_1) = n_1 \text{ and } c(L_2) = n_2 \}$

**Question 2**. Estimate $\max\{ c(L_1L_2) \mid c(L_1) = n_1 \text{ and } c(L_2) = n_2 \}$

**Question 3**. Estimate $\max\{ c(L^*) \mid c(L) = n \}$

**Answers.**

\begin{align*}
   \max\{ c(L_1 \cap L_2) \mid c(L_1) = n_1 \text{ and } c(L_2) = n_2 \}  &= n_1n_2\\
   \max\{ c(L_1L_2) \mid c(L_1) = n_1 \text{ and } c(L_2) = n_2 \} &= n_12^{n_2} - 2^{n_2-1}\\
  \max\{ c(L^*) \mid c(L) = n \} &= 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}
\end{align*}
These results hold for languages over an alphabet containing at least two-letters (and even 3 letters for the product). For one-letter alphabet, the values are also known, but are different.

**References**

S. Yu, Regular languages, in Handbook of language theory, G. Rozenberg et A. Salomaa (ed.), vol. 1, ch. 2, pp. 679–746, Springer, 1997.

For related questions, I recommend reading the articles of H. Gruber, M. Holzer, M. Kutrib, H. Petersen, where you will find plenty of further references.

Comment: @mvw I am afraid you did not get the question right, nor its answer. I am talking about worth possible complexity. I let you verify that if $L = (b + c + ac^*(a+b))^*ac^*$ and $K = (a + (b + c)(a + c)^*b)^*(b+c)(a+c)^*$, then $c(L) = c(K) = 2$ but $c(LK) = 6$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the limitation to alphabets with more than 1 letter.

Comment: This wording of the question "What are the HIGHEST number of states one would need in DFAs" gives me some troubles, as I can add arbitrary unneeded states. Your version of estimating the minimal DFA makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

My naive estimates for the number of states needed:

Concatenation $L_A+L_B$ can be detected by "chaining" $A$ and $B$ automata, thus not more than $N_A+N_B$ states.

Intersection needs running $A$ and $B$ "simultaneously", thus using the product automaton with not more than $N_A N_B$ states.

The Kleene hull ${L_A}^* = L^0 \cup L \cup L^2 \cup \ldots$ would need finite repetition of $A$. We could extend it into a $\epsilon$-NFA with extra $\epsilon$-transitions from the final states to the initial state. The number of states would not increase. Turning this into a DFA would result in a DFA with up to $2^{N_A}$ states.

All those automata could be minimized, so lower upper bounds are possible.

Comment: The question is about DFA, not NFAs.

Comment: That is exactly why the NFA is turned into a DFA.